# TextFormField selection handle is overlapping when scrolled offscreen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The problem I'm facing is that when my ListView is scrolled off view, the text selection handle can still be seen. Here's a photo for reference, it will explain it much better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/icDIU.jpg

I've only tested it on Android, I don't have an iOS device to test it on.

Here's my main widget

```
  @override
  Widget body() {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, Step1IntroViewModel>(
      converter: (store) => Step1IntroViewModel.fromStore(store),
      builder: (context, viewModel) {
        return StepMainTemplate.build(
          this.context,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildImageWidget(),
              Text(
                'Upload image',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    StepMainTemplate.title(
                      subtitle: 'Step 1 of 2',
                      title: 'Introduce yourself',
                    ),
                    ProfileForm(
                      key: _profileFormKey,
                      initProfile: viewModel.profileState?.data,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 20),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: RedOneButton.text(
                          text: "Next",
                          function: () {
                            var profile = _profileFormKey.currentState.save();
                            if (profile != null) {
                              viewModel.saveProfile(profile);
                              ExtendedNavigator.ofRouter<Router>()
                                  .pushNamed(Routes.step2Route);
                            }
                          }),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

And here's the ProfileForm

```
class ProfileForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final Profile initProfile;

  const ProfileForm({Key key, this.initProfile}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ProfileFormState createState() => ProfileFormState();
}

class ProfileFormState extends State<ProfileForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<String> genders = ['Male', 'Female'];
  List<String> positions = ['SA', 'PSA', 'PS', 'VPS'];
  String _fullName;
  String _position;
  String _gender;
  String _number;
  String _email;
  String _urlName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.initProfile != null) {
      _fullName = widget.initProfile.fullName;
      _position = widget.initProfile.position;
      _gender = widget.initProfile.gender;
      _number = widget.initProfile.phone;
      _email = widget.initProfile.email;
      _urlName = widget.initProfile.urlName;
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  Profile save() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      var profile = Profile(
          fullName: _fullName,
          position: _position,
          gender: _gender,
          phone: _number,
          email: _email,
          urlName: _urlName);
      return profile;
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                ProfileTextFormField(
                  initialValue: _fullName,
                  labelText: 'Full name',
                  hintText: 'Please enter your full name',
                  validator: (value) => Validator.validateFullName(value),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                  onSaved: (value) => _fullName = value,
                ),
                ProfileDropDownField(
                    initialValue: _position,
                    labelText: 'Position',
                    hintText: 'Please enter your position',
                    items: positions,
                    onSelected: (value) => _position = value),
                ProfileTextFormField(
                  initialValue: _number,
                  labelText: 'Phone number',
                  hintText: 'Please enter your phone number',
                  validator: (value) => Validator.validatePhone(value),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  onSaved: (value) => _number = value,
                ),
                ProfileTextFormField(
                  initialValue: _email,
                  labelText: 'Email',
                  hintText: 'Please enter your email',
                  validator: (value) => Validator.validateEmail(value),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                ),
                ProfileRadioField(
                  initialValue: _gender,
                  labelText: 'Gender',
                  items: genders,
                  onSelected: (value) => _gender = value,
                ),
                ProfileTextFormField(
                  initialValue: _urlName,
                  labelText: 'URL name',
                  hintText: 'Your preferred URL name',
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  onSaved: (value) => _urlName = value,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                ),
              ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Also related to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13182

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this problem by directly putting the TextFormField directly inside a ListView. This is the only way I could get it to work properly.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            widget.header ?? SizedBox.shrink(),
            ..._buildContentList(),
            widget.footer ?? SizedBox.shrink(),
          ],
        ));
  }

  List<Widget> _buildContentList() {
    var list = <Widget>[];
    if (widget.hasProfile) list.addAll(_buildProfileFormList());
    if (widget.hasStory) list.addAll(_buildStoryFormList());
    return list;
  }

  List<Widget> _buildProfileFormList() {
    return <Widget>[
      ProfileTextFormField(
        initialValue: _profile.fullName,
        labelText: 'Full name',
        hintText: 'Please enter your full name',
        validator: (value) => Validator.validateFullName(value),
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
        onSaved: (value) => _profile.fullName = value,
      ),
      ProfileDropDownField(
          initialValue: _profile.position,
          labelText: 'Position',
          hintText: 'Please enter your position',
          items: positions,
          onSelected: (value) => _profile.position = value),
      ProfileTextFormField(
        initialValue: _profile.phone,
        labelText: 'Phone number',
        hintText: 'Please enter your phone number',
        validator: (value) => Validator.validatePhone(value),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        onSaved: (value) => _profile.phone = value,
      ),
      ProfileTextFormField(
        initialValue: _profile.email,
        labelText: 'Email',
        hintText: 'Please enter your email',
        validator: (value) => Validator.validateEmail(value),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        onSaved: (value) => _profile.email = value,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
      ),
      ProfileRadioField(
        initialValue: _profile.gender,
        labelText: 'Gender',
        items: genders,
        onSelected: (value) => _profile.gender = value,
      ),
      ProfileTextFormField(
        initialValue: _profile.urlName,
        labelText: 'URL name',
        hintText: 'Your preferred URL name',
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        onSaved: (value) => _profile.urlName = value,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> _buildStoryFormList() {
    return <Widget>[
      ProfileTextFormField(
        initialValue: _profile.aboutYourself,
        labelText: '',
        hintText:
            '',
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        onSaved: (value) => _profile.aboutYourself = value,
        maxLines: 3,
      ),
      ProfileTextFormField(
        initialValue: _profile.sharingMessage,
        labelText: '',
        hintText: '',
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        maxLength: 300,
        onSaved: (value) => _profile.sharingMessage = value,
        maxLines: 5,
      ),
    ];
  }
```